# Вставная конструкция "в принципе"

Tags: вводные-слова, пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять вводное слово "в принципе"?

*Да, в принципе, познавательная.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном Вами предложении слова "в принципе" можно заменить "вообще говоря", а это явная вводная конструкция, поэтому запятые Вы расставили верно.

Answer (score 1):

Если "в принципе"  имеет значение "в сущности говоря", "по сути говоря", то оно выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

Член предложения (обстоятельство). То же, что "принципиально", "в основном", "в целом". Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

В вашем примере возможна как постановка запятой, так и ее отсутствие. Все зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая зависит от контекста. Лично я использую такой практический критерий (не научный, но понятный): если есть уверенность - невводное, если неуверенность - вводное. Ср.: *Я, в принципе, сладкого не ем* (неуверенность: не ем, но могу и съесть). *Я в принципе сладкого не ем* (уверенность: никогда не ем).

У вас: *Да, в принципе, познавательная* (неуверенность: можно назвать познавательной, но с оговоркой; познавательная с натяжкой; пожалуй, познавательная, хотя это не очевидно, героя пытались в этом убедить, и он почти согласился). *Да, в принципе познавательная* (уверенность: бесспорно познавательная).

Вот что пишет Словарь вводных слов:

В ПРИНЦИПЕ, наречие.

1.**Редко** употребляется в функции вводного для выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, интонационно выделяется (разг.): *С такой головой, в принципе* (**= между прочим, конечно**), *можно и не работать* (С.Довлатов); *В принципе, да* (А.Грин); *Я, в принципе, сладкого не ем* (С.Довлатов).

Сравни (**читать с логическим ударением** на обстоятельство «в принципе»): *С такой головой в принципе* (*= вообще, совсем*) *можно и не работать*.

2.**Невводное**, употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия в значении «**в основном, в общем, вообще, совсем**», не обособляется: *Значит, в принципе мир можно восстановить* (Ф.Искандер); *Бродский говорил, что любит метафизику и сплетни. И добавлял: «Что в принципе одно и то же»* (С.Довлатов).